# Run Ganache GUI on ubuntu

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, truffle, ganache

I want to run ganache Gui app on ubuntu 22.04. After downloading AppImage I run it using command
`ganache-2.5.4-linux-x86_64.AppImage --appimage-extract`

It generates new folder and then I execute `./Ganache` inside that folder.

I get this message

**[50883:0717/002902.307174:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(1034)] The display compositor is frequently crashing. Goodbye.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)**

How can I fix this ?

Comment: I recommend asking this question on https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for ubuntu 22.04 here: https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE

just run these commands:
`sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt install libfuse2`

Answer (score 1):

You should `chmod +x ganache-2.5.4-linux-x86_64.AppImage` and turn it into an executable. Then you can run it double clicking it.

You could also move it into the `opt` folder to be available to all users with the command `sudo mv ganache-2.5.4-linux-x86_64.AppImag /opt/`

And then, you could create a desktop link to be used in the menu, creating a file with the contents like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ganache
Exec=/opt/ganache-2.5.4-linux-x86_64.AppImage
comment=cloud
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Utility;
```

Then, when you run it, you can pin it to your panel! :D

Comment: I did that. The problem is after that still can not run ganache command and terminal show this message **50883:0717/002902.307174:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(1034)] The display compositor is frequently crashing. Goodbye. Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)**